# Logistic regression is slow

Tags: classification, logistic, python

I am relatively new to machine learning and I have a data classification problem where each sample has ~1500 features (continuous) and the category is binary.

I want to apply logistic regression, for learning purposes. I have done a vectorized implementation in Python, which works very well and is fast on other datasets with a smaller number of features (order of magnitude 10s-100s features).
On my dataset, however, I can't even finish the training (on ~3000 samples), as it simply takes ages.

Could this be a problem of: 1) my vectorization, 2) the number of features in a sample (time for some dimensionality reduction?), 3) the fact that the problem is not suited to logistic regression, 4) using Python, or something else altogether?

Comment: Do you mean that for each binary response you have ~1500 explanatory variables? :O

Comment: I can say little on your particular implementation, but if you use a standard logistic regression I would suggest switching to some sort of penalized logistic model. 1500 features with 3000 samples will lead to an overfitting problem. Maybe search for an Elastic Net or Lasse implementation in Python.

Comment: @Procrastinator Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Erik By "penalized", do you mean "regularized"? Just making sure it's only a difference in terminology :)

Comment: @Erik And of course thank you for the suggestion -- my meek reputation here doesn't allow for an upvote.

Comment: Cristina, can you successfully do a *linear regression* on your data on the machine you are using? How long does it take? How long do, say, 10 or 20 repeat iterations take to run? This should give you a crude bound on what to expect for *logistic* regression. Much more than that and either your features are forcing a very difficult or unstable fit or you have an implementation bottleneck. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks, this is a good idea, I'll try it out.

Comment: Cristina, I just tried this (admittedly on a fairly beefy machine) with $n=3000$ and $p=1500$ in R with random features and response. A single linear regression took less than 8 seconds and logistic less than 3 minutes using `glm`. Some responses are bound to be fit very hard as mentioned by other posters. You might look at Paul Komarek's C implementation which is specifically designed for bigger problems like this. Note that computation increases roughly as the cube of the number of features.

Comment: Oh, I would be happy even with "less than 30 minutes", the way it's been running on my machine :D Thanks a lot for the data, that's a great reference threshold. I find this is a problem when starting up with something, one lacks the "gut feeling" for the expected/average values.

Comment: Cristina, yes. In case the reasoning behind my first suggestion was not entirely clear, one common way of fitting logistic regression models is via iterative weighted least squares, that is, by solving a *sequence* of linear regression problems. It is rare in practice for more than 20 iterations to be needed, even in big problems.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- I'm using BFGS for optimizing the cost and I've seen (in my other datasets) that it does around 15-18 iterations. Thank you for taking the time to explain! I did the Stanford online ML course with Andrew Ng and he explained incredibly well, but sometimes it's hard translating that knowledge to non-toy datasets.

Comment: @cardinal I have used more extensive logging now; linear, as well as logistic, regression does not converge -- the cost stays more or less constant from iteration to iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, considering you use a custom algorithm and that overfitting might be or might not be involved, it's really hard to say. So what are your possibilites? 1. Your algorithm might be badly written 2. The algorithm you use might be a bad choice 3.  The algorithm does not converge (overfitting or collinearity, and has no alternative stopping condition 4. Unknown issue with Python.

The third options seems very likely, but all are very possible.

A recipe to get you a bit further is to just print (or log to a file) all the intermediate steps of your algorithm, the updated solution (I assume an iterative algorithm) and so on. This might just help pinpoint what is going wrong. For example, an indicator for overfitting can be that the coefficients get extremely large.

I just tried the same with R with a response binomially distributed (p=0.5) and 1500 normally distributed (mean=0, sd = 1, independent) features and no connection to the response. It finished after 1-2 minutes but warned me that it did not converge. Coefficients got very large (E13) -> overfitting.

Comment: I think I'll try the regularized version first, since that seems the most reasonable according to other sources as well. I switched to using a BFGS implementation from scipy instead of my own gradient descent implementation in order to speed things up, so I'm a bit limited in what I can observe and log directly. The cost function is getting lower over time -- it just takes a lot of time! :-) Thanks for the suggestions, I have some good starting points now.

Comment: When you have that many features, I've found that `glmnet` in R usually does very well.  It uses a Coordinate Descent algorithm that gives a full regularization path and is usually amazingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

What are your convergence criteria? Most standard statistical software won't try to invert approximately singular matricies and throw errors when the determinant is found to be impossibly small. Your algorithms may be missing such spot-checking. I'm certain this design matrix is singular since $n = 2p$.

Without going any further, I would recommend you use LASSO for estimating this model. It's a tried, established, and extremely effective way of data reduction when the number of features is so large compared to the sample size.